# Compare two worksheets and built new with duplicates from both

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a code that will compare two worksheets and collect duplicates to another worksheet. Target is to:

1. Detect duplicate
2. Copy duplicate row from worksheet Germany to Sheet1
3. Copy duplicate row from worksheet Austria below previous to Sheet1
4. continue until all duplicates are listed from both worksheets Germany and Austria to Sheet1

I have this code, but the problem is that it collects only duplicates. So if I have 24 duplicates in total, on Sheet1 I would like to see all of them from both worksheets Germany and Austria to be able to compare all the other information.

My data is in columns A:K. I am comparing data by column B.

My current code:

```
Sub CopyDuplicates()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, lc1 As Long, lc2 As Long, r As Long
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws1 = Sheets("Germany")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Austria")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet1")

ws3.Cells.Clear
lr2 = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lc1 = ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
lc2 = ws2.UsedRange.Columns.Count

ws1.UsedRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
ws2.UsedRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

Set rng = ws2.Range("B2:B" & lr2)
For Each cell In rng
    If Application.CountIf(ws1.Range("B:B"), cell.Value) > 0 Then
        r = Application.Match(cell.Value, ws1.Range("B:B"), 0)
        'ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(r, 1), ws1.Cells(r, lc1)).Interior.Color = vbRed
        'ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(r, 1), ws2.Cells(r, lc2)).Interior.Color = vbRed
        cell.EntireRow.Copy ws3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)
    End If
Next cell
ws3.Rows(1).Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "the problem is that it collects only duplicates" - sorry, what is the problem, I don't understand? Don't you want to collect duplicates?

Comment: Is this a one-off task, or something you'll want to do regularly? You might want to consider just adding a column (temporary or otherwise) which indicates whether the row is a duplicate, and then filter on that.

Comment: Current code is merging duplicates. So if it finds duplicate on two worksheets, it is copying only one "to show that it is duplicate". I need to have both of them from both worksheets one after another to compare all the other data in easy way. `cell.EntireRow.Copy ws3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)` this string is copying only one row from one worksheet. It should detect duplicate, copy from worksheet Germany and Austria. So instead of 1 row there should be 2 on worksheet Sheet1. One from Germany another one from Austria

Comment: Your code only copies `cell`'s row so you also need to copy the `r`th row of the Germany sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add the line below to your loop.

```
For Each cell In rng
    If Application.CountIf(ws1.Range("B:B"), cell.Value) > 0 Then
        r = Application.Match(cell.Value, ws1.Range("B:B"), 0)
        ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(r, 1), ws1.Cells(r, lc1)).Interior.Color = vbRed
        ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(r, 1), ws2.Cells(r, lc2)).Interior.Color = vbRed
        'added line below
        ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(r, 1), ws1.Cells(r, lc1)).Copy ws3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)
        cell.EntireRow.Copy ws3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)
    End If
Next cell
```